# find resultant XYZ points in a laser 3D scanner

Tags: python, math, 3d

I am working on a 3D scanner using a laser and camera and some other stuff needed, 
the idea is that the camera captures an image to the target when the laser is on, then use the image to gain the laser line as `X` and `Y` coordinates.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg7Yd.png) for explanation.

My question here is: how could i use these coordinates to generate the `Z` point in order to plot the 3D surface?

for better understanding link for an image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLhMu.png)

The target is on a circular disk "it is not shown in the image" with a known radius

Comment: So is your problem figuring out the math, the programming, or both? For math, you'd find better luck [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/). For programming, please post some code for us to see what you've attempted and potentially point you in the right direction. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @areuexperienced My problem is figuring the math out

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as OP's comment makes clear, it is firstly a question of maths.

Comment: I agree with HighPerformanceMark ... btw the images did not tell us anything about the principle of 3D scanig you want to use ...  the laser and camera angles are fixed or you are driving them to obtain theta angle when they connect to use triangulation?  or LASER and Camera directions are fixed and you obtaining angle from LASER Spot xy position? or use different principle like LIDAR or else ...  what are knowns and unknowns (distances,FOV...) what exactly is the problem ? The first image does not look like a LASER spot or object ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read a little of theory... Start from here:

https://lesagegp.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/laser-scanning-explained/

Here a practical application with a python application. This guy then elaborated the point cloud within meshlab:

http://shortcircuitsandinfiniteloops.blogspot.it/2014/10/androidioio-3d-laser-scanner.html

Pay attention to reflective surfaces. You can get better results scanning objects in a dark room.

More theory:

- http://www.researchgate.net/publication/253145412_Basic_theory_on_surface_measurement_uncertainty_of_3D_imaging_systems
- https://books.google.it/books?id=7gOspY2t1Q0C&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=formula+triangulation+laser+scanner+3d+camera&source=bl&ots=GEtKtF5f0X&sig=Gi2Qf5yRM94IV5zHaaVTs4ZrftU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBGoVChMIuf39iq6SyAIVDGsUCh14RglG#v=onepage&q=formula%20triangulation%20laser%20scanner%203d%20camera&f=false